# Adobe was hanging up upon opening a file - change of default computer fixed it. Why?

Tags: windows-vista, adobe-photoshop

Our designer's copy of Adobe Photoshop suddenly started hanging up when she would try to open a file.  After some research I found a forum in which it was suggested to change the default printer - that this had fixed it for other users with the same problem.

It worked.  My question is, WHY did it work?

Comment: Ask Adobe. It's their bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general speaking, even if this is adobe bug, many programs need to know some thinks from the printer when they open - for some reason they do not have take care this case that the printer send problematic data.

What needs a program won to know from the printer ? the default paper size, and the printing resolution to know what to show on preview, and on some infos that shows together with.

Now the problem maybe is not 100% from adobe, the printer driver can stop working and hung when ps ask for default size for example.

Comment: This makes sense as she was working with non-standard sizes for UK clients.  So A4 size instead of 8.5x10

Thanks!